# Existing CodeIgniter application folder in new CodeIgniter installation

Tags: php, codeigniter, webserver

A project I am an app developer on has recently lost its web service developer, this has left me holding the bag with very little knowledge of what I am doing. I was given a repo with the 'application' folder from the CodeIgniter project and nothing else. I downloaded a new copy of CI, installed on server and began copying the existing stuff into the new install, I did this slowly so I could see what would inevitably break.

And break something has, when I direct to the folder that the install is in i.e www.example.com/dashboard CI does its thing and redirects me to the auth controller and login function and then promptly throws a 404.

My thinking is that the previous developer enabled one of the CI features that cleans up URLs, however, as I said my experience is extremely limited. I have checked the application/config folders as thoroughly as I can, set the base_url, set the database values but I am throughly out of ideas.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be a God send as this project is scheduled to close very soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run that file with this url

```
www.example.com/index.php/dashboard
```

Comment: How do you suggest I remove this requirement? As the application doesn't seem to know to form the URL this way, LOTS of dead links.

Comment: For anyone in the future, fixed with a .htaccess file as described on the ellislab/CI website.